# Error when loading RolesCrudController using Backpack for Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel-backpack

When I try to load the RolesCrudController using Backpack for Laravel it doesn't load any of the roles and just shows an error saying `Error Loading Page, please refresh the page.`

When I look at the console there is a 500 internal error referencing `role/search`.

If I type something into the search box it will return matching roles correctly and I can edit the roles. It's just when I initially load {{ backpack_url('role') }} and have nothing stored in the local storage for the search field on this controller that I get the error above.

I'm using the latest version of backpack and the latest version of the permissions manager.

I've cleared the cache, routes, views, configs. This doesn't help.

Comment: take a look at that 500 internal error at `role/search` set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` to get the full error in your network console in chrome. or you can see `storage/log/laravel.log`. what does it say?

Comment: I have APP_DEBUG=true set, nothing shows up in the log or in the console.

Comment: You should be able to show the error in the ajax request `/admin/role/search` without it you cannot know what's wrong exactly

Comment: It just gives a 500 internal error. It doesn’t list any response in the network request console or any more information related to the error in the chrome console. If I could find it I would post that or use it to figure out the problem.

Comment: What about apache/nginx error log? Or php error log?